# Jquery getJSON Get Data

Tags: jquery, json

When the <kbd>Get Data</kbd> button is pushed, I need to fetch the data for the names of races using JSON. The URL to load the JSON `http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/races/` and display the race list in the `div#getResults`.

I need to add the race `ID` into the opening `li` tag as an `id` attribute
value. For example, the `Storm King Run` race would be `<li id="1">`.
When the user clicks on one of the races from this list, the names of
runners in the race will display. Use the race `ID`, stored as the `id`
attribute value and appended to the `results` URL, to fetch the data for the
list of runner’s names. The URL to load JSON is:
`http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/results/<add race ID>`

*(Note: The race ID number needs to be concatenated at the end of
the URL to be able to access the data.)*

Display the information under the `div#showResults`.Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, please?

```js
$("getList").click(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/races/", function(json) {
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      $("showResults").append(field + " ");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#getResults li {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="getList" type="button">Get Data</button>
<div>
  <ul id='getResults'></ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul id='showResults'></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? One thing of note is that you seem to be mixing your `json` and `result` variables. More specifically, `result` is not defined and should be `json`

Comment: Solid start, in jquery, when you are referencing id you need to prepend the selector with `#`, for class use `.`, when nothing is used, it is considered element name, like div

Comment: Don't include both `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`. You want only the full version; jQuery-slim has no AJAX functions (like `$.getJSON()`)

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. I made all those changes, no errors in the console, but still not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: currently what do you require to be printed isnide the `ul`?

Comment: the 2 `getResults` and `showResults` what should they have listed inside ?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the current state of your code

Comment: you are using `$.each(result` but in here its `function(json)`..try to change `result` to  `json` or the other way around..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display all the race names on the click of the button and when clicked on the race name you want to send a request to the API and fetch the results along with the respective id, if that is correct then you can use the following, it may not show you the desired results on StackOverflow and show something like this in console

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   '[Jquery getJSON Get Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224093/jquery-getjson-get-data#)'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest
>   endpoint 'http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/races/'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

and the API does not support https so you might have to run it locally on your computer to test it I have tested with the hardcoded JSON response from the server. Hope it helps.

```js
$("#getList").on('click', function() {

  $.getJSON("http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/races/", function(result) {

    var races = result.races;
    $.each(races, function(index, race) {

      var race_id = race.id;
      var race_name = race.race_name;

      $("<li></li>", {
        id: race_id
      }).html(race_name).appendTo("#getResults");

      $("#" + race_id).on('click', function() {
        $.getJSON("http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/results/" +
          race_id + '/',
          function(race_result) {
            var results = race_result.results;
            $('#showResults').empty();
            $.each(results, function(i, runners) {
              $("<li></li>").html(runners.name).prependTo(
                "#showResults");
            });
          });
      });
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#getResults li {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="getList" type="button">Get Data</button>
<div>
  <ul id='getResults'></ul>


  <ul id='showResults'></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! This has worked to get the races to display, can you tell me how I can get the results to display when the race is clicked? The results are displayed using "http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/results/1/"  the 1 at the end is for the 1st race, Storm King Run, and then changes to 2-6 for the other ones.

Comment: it is already done you click on the race name and it will fetch the racer names and show you @AllisonGandara

Comment: Ok, I will check my code again. I'm not seeing the racer names when clicked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you must have some error in console, see if the request completed from the API? @AllisonGandara and the response is received

Comment: and verify if the `ul.showResults` is available in the html

Comment: Oh yes, console is telling me this. Any ideas? Failed to load http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/results/5: Redirect from 'http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/results/5' to 'http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/results/5/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: are you trying to run it here on stackoverflow? @AllisonGandara

Comment: I have tried it both here and on my original (after updating code) and get the same error in console.

Comment: its because you need to add the `/` in the end of the `url` `"http://itweb.fvtc.edu/wetzel/marathon/results/" + race_id+"/"` i have updated the code @AllisonGandara

Comment: Gah, you're awesome! That did it, thank you! One more question.. when I click on the first race, the names appear. But when I click the next races, the names from the first race are still there along with the second race. Is there anyway to get the previous results to disappear when a new race is clicked?

Comment: i have updated that too ;) check now @AllisonGandara

Comment: do vote up and mark the answer as correct if it works for you. @AllisonGandara